# Use Ghostscript to set PDF natural language via pdfmarks

Tags: pdf, accessibility, ghostscript

I'm setting metadata on PDFs using Ghostscript and pdfmarks. I'm able to set just about everything I need IE: Title, Author, Bookmarks, etc using pdfmarks. However, I can not set the Natural Language. I'm sure I'm just missing the correct syntax, as I've looked over Adobe documentation and see it listed in there.

This is what I have tried:

```
[ /Type /Catalog /Lang (en-US) /StPNE pdfmark
[ /Subtype /document /Lang (en-US) /StPNE pdfmark
```

Neither of these works, unfortunately. Does anyone know the correct syntax to add a language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a logical structure pdfmark `StPNE`, but the last pdfmark reference I can find (version 9 from 2008) does not list /Lang as a legal attribute for a logical structure pdfmark.

I note that the PDF specification does permit /Lang to be a member of a logical structure element, but that doesn't mean there's a pdfmark for it. I think Adobe stopped updating the pdfmark reference with new content for new versions of the PDF specification.

/Type /Catalog won't be legal either.

Can you explain which part of the resulting PDF you are trying to add this to ? Ghostscript **only** implements the pdfmarks listed in the pdfmark refrence, and I don't think it fully implements all of those currently.

[EDIT]

I just checked and Ghostscript's pdfwrite device does not implement the StPNE pdfmark at all, so that's not going to do anything.

[further edit]

It **may** be (looking at the PDF specification) that what you want is to set a key called /Lang in the Catalog object of the PDF file. Obviously I'm not certain but....

```
[{Catalog} <</Lang (en-US)>> /PUT pdfmark
```

puts a key called /Lang in the Catalog dictionary, and assigns it the string value (en-US). That may be sufficient, I can't tell.

Comment: I'm running the PDF that I generate through an accessibility checker. The Natural Language is not set, so I'm trying to fix that.

Comment: Also found this: https://ghostscript.com/~robin/pdf_reference17.pdf

Which references the /Lang switch

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what the accessibility checker is looking for. Obviously you don't either, which is fair enough, but random guessing of pdfmarks isn't going to fix it. The PDF file you are pointing at is the PDF 1.7 Reference Manual which I **did** say in my answer permits /Lang to be an element in a logical structure element. But as I also pointed out, there does not seem to be a specified pdfmark to set that. In which case, you can't do it via a pdfmark. It may not be obvious, but you'd need to set /Lang for **every** structure element, you can't set one for the whole document.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. Looks like I'm out of luck on this one. The checkers I use basically just say that the 'Natural Language' is not set, which led me to the /Lang option, but you're right I'm kind of assuming that would be the fix.

Comment: YES!!! That did it! My checker is showing it as the following: Language: Custom/Empty, Custom Language: en-US. Works great in both of my accessibility checkers. Thank you so much!